# what is the significance of lighting camphor infront of god?

Tags: rituals, gods, practice

In Hinduism, we light camphor to the God statues in the temples. what is the symbol of that. In addition, we also give aarati.

What exactly is it mean , and why must one do it?

Comment: one possible meaning: camphor refers to our desires and tendencies and eogs. Just as the camphor fire finally consumes the camphor and no more camphor is left, similarly we surrender all our egos to God and thereby they burn under the influence of the Lord, finally no more to be seen in us. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Hinduism, Aarti is an important part of daily worship. 
Very good question. 
There are lots of things we do in the daily routine life but lots of them do not make sense in common logic but we have to check back on History. Here it is explained in simple words by BAPS Sanstha

Bochasanvasi Shree Aksharpurshottam Sansatha explained significance of Aarti in simeple words here....

"Aarti is the symbolic waving of a lighted wick in a clockwise motion in front of the murti of Bhagwan while singing a prayer. It symbolizes the removal of darkness by true spiritual enlightenment. Aarti is a tradition dating back thousands of years. In ancient times, there was little light inside the mandirs, and even less light actually reached the garbha gruh, or the inner sanctum of the mandir where the murtis are located. The only way to have darshan of the murtis was from the light cast from a divo, a clay lamp with a cotton wick dipped in ghee. During aarti, this lamp was held near each part of the murti so that devotees could properly see all the parts of the murti. Today, millions of Hindus devoutly perform aarti in their homes or attend aarti at mandirs everyday."(http://www.baps.org/Spiritual-Living/Hindu-Practices/Aarti.aspx)

Aarti is the ancient practice of waving a lighted wick in a clockwise motion around a murti while singing a prayer.  It symbolizes the removal of darkness by true spiritual enlightenment.  Devotees typically perform aarti twice in their ghar mandir, once in the morning and again at night.  In traditional Hindu mandirs, aarti is performed 5 times a day. (http://www.baps.org/About-BAPS/WhoWeAre/BasicBeliefs/Practices.aspx)